Is there any way in sqlglot to parse update statements into scopes
I want to get source tables and their columns from update statement by using sqlglot.
I'v tried to use build_scope() for AST of update statement, but it returns None.
from sqlglot import parse_one
from sqlglot.optimizer.scope import build_scope

qry = '''
UPDATE table_1 t1
SET foo = 'new_value'
FROM table_2 t2
    JOIN table_3 t3 ON t3.id = t2.t3_id
WHERE
    t2.id = t1.t2_id
    AND t3.bar = True;
'''

qry_ast = parse_one(qry, dialect="postgres")
root = build_scope(qry_ast)
type(root)
# NoneType

So I can't use .traverse() to get sourse tables from query, because of:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'traverse'

Update statements that I'm going to analyze may have subqueries with alias, and I need actual table names.
Is there any way to get this from update statements by using sqlglot? What am I doing wrong?
